# Tor Browser Bundle's version of Firefox [Tor Browser] is recognized as the main Firefox installation [Ubuntu 12.04]

Tags: 12.04, unity, firefox, tor

Whenever I run the start-tor-browser script to run Tor-Browser-Bundle, the Unity3D launcher stacks it with the Firefox shortcut I have on there as if it's another window of Firefox, unlike before when Unity3D launched it with a separate icon and place in the launcher.

This problem started since I upgraded Unity and Firefox to the latest version.

Also, once (after this problem had *started*) I started Tor-Browser after I had Firefox open, [the page on TorProject.org that tests if I have the browser configured for Tor or not](https://check.torproject.org/) [which is the homepage of the tor-browser-bundle] reported that the browser wasn't configured to be used with Tor.

How can I solve the problem?
That is, how can I fix the isuue of my system not recognizing the Tor-Browser as a separate app instead of Firefox?
Should I downgrade Firefox/Unity?

I use the latest Tor Obfsproxy Browser Bundle [linux-i686-2.4.6-alpha-2-dev-en-US]
And I'm on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is due to torbrowser is derived from firefox and while starting your application, your desktop-environment looks for a place where to stick it - as far as i remember the standard all Linux DEs follow is [xdg](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/XDG).

To give your system knowledge about this application, you have to put a `*.desktop`-file in either `~.local/share/applications/` or `/usr/share/applications/`.

In your case, open a terminal and `cd` into your `tor-browser`-directory from here issue `cp start-tor-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/start-tor-browser.desktop` You can also use any file-manager for this operation.